# Kendo grid for angular cannot export index column to excel

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I'm using angular 10 with kendo, now I have the problem with export excel from kendo grid, I html can preview normally, but when export as excel it have no id field. here is my code

**html**

```html
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="products" [height]="400">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">
      Download Excel
    </button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column title="id">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      {{ rowIndex + 1 }}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="pname" title="Product name"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx"></kendo-grid-excel>
</kendo-grid>
```

**ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { aggregateBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { productList } from './products';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    products = productList;
}
```

**productList**

```js
export const productList = [
  { pname: 'Coca-Cola'},
  { pname: 'Sprite'},
  { pname: 'Pepsi'},
  { pname: 'Red Bull'},
  { pname: 'Fanta'},
  { pname: 'Olate'},
  { pname: 'Boos-trong'},
  { pname: 'Karabao'},
  { pname: 'M150'}
];
```

and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwqzfp-cc3yf5?file=app/products.ts) is my code in stackbiz

Please help to solve this problem, Thank in advance.

Comment: The ids should be part of the data. Since,you are you are using only the template and computing them,it wont be included in the excel.Add the ids to the productList and write the code same way for how you did with pname.

Comment: @Priyankarao thank for your reply, but if I export as PDF it work, So I wonder why PDF work but Excel not work, could you explain me clearly?

Comment: The workings of both of them are quite different. Export to PDF takes what is in the canvas that is being displayed. Therefore, you actually get the checkboxes or any HTML elements for that matter too in your pdf.But the that way Export to Excel doesnt work the same.You only get values. I suggest you to play around with the grids in stackblitz mentioned in the telerik website.